ImageFont.truetype() Fonts in tkinter - do I need to know the file extension? (e.g. 'arial.ttf')
I pulled a list of available fonts from the tkinter 'font' module.
from tkinter import font ... font.families())

However, when trying to select a font through the ImageFont class, I'm really struggling to match the font names (from above) with the font .ttf file.
my_font = ImageFont.truetype(f"{some_font_from_above}.ttf")

Is it an upper/lowercase issue? Or font names differing from .ttf file names?
Thanks,
Getting the same error:
self.font = core.getfont(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: cannot open resource


As far as I know, there is no class ImageFont in tkinter.  The ImageFont class is in the python imaging library (PIL), and is used to draw text on PIL.Image objects.  The font family names that you get from tkinter are not the same as the font file names, unfortunately.  Somewhere on your computer (it's operating system dependent) is a directory with font files in it.  You find the one(s) you want to load through PIL.  The PIL docs aren't very clear but once loaded, it appears that you can call the getname() function to verify that you have the one you want. I hope that helps.

You can try using matplotlib.font_manager.findfont() to get the full pathname of the specified font name.

thanks a lot - I'll check this out
